# Adding boxed texts on commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to draw this commutative diagram (source: Elements of Algebraic Topology by James Munkres). I know how to draw the diagram using tikzcd without the boxes. Can someone help me about how to add these boxes on the tikzcd diagram? [image]

Comment: Please provide the code for the tikzcd version. AFAIR tikzcd can name the main cells, and thus you can subsequently add the boxes relative to these cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place the boxes in the middle as labels “near end”, but a bit lowered and with smashed depth. For the upper boxes, I use `\overset`, but making the boxes zero width for safety.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\sboxed}[1]{%
  \,\raisebox{-1ex}[\height][0pt]{\fbox{$\scriptstyle\mathstrut#1$}}%
}
\newcommand{\uboxed}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\fbox{$\scriptstyle\mathstrut#1$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge,column sep=large]
0 \arrow[r] &
C_{p+1} \arrow[r,"\phi"] \arrow[d,"\partial_C"',"\sboxed{c_p}" near end] &
\overset{\uboxed{d_{p+1}}}{D_{p+1}}
  \arrow[r,"\psi"] \arrow[d,"\partial_D"',"\sboxed{d_p}" near end] &
\overset{\uboxed{e_{p+1}}}{E_{p+1}}
  \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"\partial_E"',"\sboxed{e_p}" near end] &
0 \\
0 \arrow[r] &
C_{p} \arrow[r,"\phi"] \arrow[d,"\partial_C"',"\sboxed{c_{p-1}}" near end] &
D_{p} \arrow[r,"\psi"] \arrow[d,"\partial_D"',] &
E_{p} \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"\partial_E"'] &
0 \\
0 \arrow[r] &
C_{p-1} \arrow[r,"\phi"] &
D_{p-1} \arrow[r,"\psi"] &
E_{p-1} \arrow[r] &
0
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AtonuRoyChowdhury Maybe there are better Ti*k*Z ways, but… ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are better TikZ ways (using the node option `label`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{% my label style:
  myls/.style={
    draw, text height=height("$d$")
    }
  }
  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
0 \arrow[r] &
C_{p+1} \arrow[r,"\phi"] \arrow[d,"\partial_C"'] & |[label={[myls]d_{p+1}}]|D_{p+1}
  \arrow[r,"\psi"] \arrow[d,"\partial_D"'] &
|[label={[myls]e_{p+1}}]|E_{p+1}
  \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"\partial_E"'] &
0 \\
0 \arrow[r] &
|[label={[myls]45:c_p}]|C_{p} \arrow[r,"\phi"] \arrow[d,"\partial_C"'] &
|[label={[myls]45:d_p}]|D_{p} \arrow[r,"\psi"] \arrow[d,"\partial_D"',] &
|[label={[myls]45:e_p}]|E_{p} \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"\partial_E"'] &
0 \\
0 \arrow[r] &
|[label={[myls]45:c_{p-1}}]|C_{p-1} \arrow[r,"\phi"] &
D_{p-1} \arrow[r,"\psi"] &
E_{p-1} \arrow[r] &
0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]